# react-facebook-login reloads the page instead of opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-login

I am using the **react-facebook-login** package by keppelen.

The normal flow is when i click the **login with facebook button** it just open a new tab redirecting to facebook login.

But sometimes, instead of opening in new tab it appends to my current url and reloads the page.

**http://localhost/my_url**?code=AQBbCtyyb27tal6F4e6EPRUQKOtKwPhszK0UBZIH00faWy6VUJwS3AIWrcS87_2hBSragOo8kGF2hFxTgZqm_0TRPcYBjwe0LjKlOqcu4lYd8GX1Xou0ZnFjqgul8UH-BeGkiK0rKSXz12LB87h4YxP8Dqs_DnQtz4eYQ4cChCUKg60uLXoPXECSV3y2w2fGGRUCe7qgsWFAlkHQ8k5hERd79DbzBIRn2hvKRZuD7Al9AEZ5KymSJ3phaHTeSGQtoIchUUgDJPoO3_Yj34mNH3eYuGTNJ58KN-5aVSP9uwL2_2F43UtSIie5IYINEyVITUO1RIy9a94&state=facebookdirect#*=*

And of course i got some error because the url is not existing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you fixed it already but for anyone that has the same problem:
[react-facebook-login npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook-login) is outdated.
Go to [react-facebook-login github page](https://github.com/keppelen/react-facebook-login) and you will find a `disableMobileRedirect` prop.
Just put that prop to true and problem fixed :)